# Div 'twitching' upon load and hover effect not working properly

Tags: html, css

I have a div that is acting as a navigation bar for my webpage. The div consists of a horizontal unordered list where each list item is an image. The unordered list has a fade-in animation on load, and each list item has a hover effect where it grows in scale upon mouseover.

For some reason, whenever I load the page, either in Dreamweaver's live view screen or as a preview on the web browser, the div starts a few pixels off the position to the right, and once the fade-in animation is completed, it 'twitches' back to its proper position.

Its very frustrating because this is not complicated code. I only have the Source Code page and its CSS stylesheet loaded in the project.

This is all the HTML code related to the Navigation bar:

```
<div class="Nav">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src="icons/filmicon.png" width="120px" height="120px" alt="Filmography"><br/>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="icons/cameraicon.png" width="120px" height="120px" alt="Photography"><br/>
        </li>
        <li id="josh">
            <img src="img/joshforsite.png"  width="300px" height="300px" alt="About Me"><br/>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="icons/designicon.png"  width="120px" height="120px" alt="Design"><br/>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="icons/brandicon.png"  width="120px" height="120px" alt="Branding"><br/>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

...and this is all the CSS code related to the Navigation bar:

```
.Nav {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: center;
list-style-type: none;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
padding-top: 16%;
white-space: nowrap;

.Nav li {
vertical-align: middle;
display: inline-block;
padding-right: 4%;
opacity: 1;
-webkit-animation: fadein 2s; 
   -moz-animation: fadein 2s; 
    -ms-animation: fadein 2s; 
     -o-animation: fadein 2s; 
        animation: fadein 2s;
        transition: all .3s ease-in-out; 

.Nav li:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
            transform: scale(1.2);

@keyframes fadein { from { opacity: 0; } to { opacity: 1; }}
@-moz-keyframes fadein { from { opacity: 0; } to { opacity: 1; }}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {from { opacity: 0; }to { opacity: 1; }}
@-o-keyframes fadein { from { opacity: 0; } to { opacity: 1; }}
```

Again, I am a beginner at HTML & CSS so I don't how much of a mess the coding is.

[Here](https://youtu.be/naDIIMErEPM) is a link to a YouTube video I uploaded showing the problem. It also shows towards the end a second issue I'm having whereby the growing hover effect is bugged. Any help with this would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: can you fiddle it?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Change the padding-right on .Nav li to a px based solution instead of a percentage and it should eliminate that jump left.

Also, you're missing your closing curly brackets for each block.

Answer (score 0):

You are using images with alternative text. The glitching is probably caused by loading the images. Try to preload the images with javascript and it might help.